# кодировка в ключах массива

Tags: php

У меня есть массив, ключами которого являются слова на украинском языке

```
$item = array
    (
        ["Артикул"] => 012310
        [Код комплекту] => 922380
        [Код товару] => 313576
        [Номенклатура] => Брюки
        [Бренд] => Aziz
        [Колір] => т-синій
        [Розмір] => 80
        [Стать] => для хлопчика
        [Класифікація] => 
        [Рік] => 
        [Сезон] => Весна
        [Країна виробництва] => Туреччина
        [Матеріал] => Габардин
        [Конструкція] => Низ
        [Утеплювач] => 
        [Група товару] => Брюки
        [Колекція] => 
        [Особливість] => 
        [Склад тканини] => Бавовна100%
        [Упаковка] => 0
        [Кількість у упаковці] => 1
        [TGroup] => 
        [Кількість у залишку] => 1
        [Ціна] => 84.30
    )
```

Он мне приходит из csv файла, который я парсю.

У меня есть массив моих полей, в которые я должен загнать приходящие данные

```
$vars = Array
    (
        [available] => Кількість у залишку
        [id] => Код товару
        [name] => name
        [model] => Номенклатура
        [title] => title
        [categoryId] => categoryId
        [price] => Ціна
        [old_price] => old_price
        [rrc_price] => rrc_price
        [picture] => picture
        [barcode] => barcode
        [vendorcode] => "Артикул"
        [param] => Стать
        [description] => description
        [country_of_origin] => country_of_origin
        [vendor] => Бренд
        [step-quantity] => step-quantity
        [min-quantity] => min-quantity
        [url] => url
    )
```

Много ума не надо, чтобы загнать все данные в нужные поля:

```
foreach ($arr['items'] as $k => $item){
    foreach ($vars as $field => $provider_field){
        $array[$i][field] = $item[$provider_field];
    }
    $i++;
}
```

и вот тут я получаю все соль ситуации
`mb_detect_encoding($provider_field)` у меня возвращает `UTF-8`
а
`mb_detect_encoding($field)` возвращает `ASCII`

скорее всего поэтому `$item[$provider_field]` в тех случаях, когда в `$provider_field` есть украинские буквы у меня не существует и эти элементы массива не заполняются.
Хотя, если вручную для теста прописать `$array[$i][field] = $item['Цiна'];` , то всё работает.

Один интересный момент: приходящий массив из файла приходит в UTF потому что я перезаписываю файл перед открытием:

```
$data = file_get_contents($filename);
$provider_encoding = mb_detect_encoding($data);
$data = iconv($provider_encoding,"UTF-8", $data);
file_put_contents($filename,$data);
```

а вот элементы массива $vars, который я же создаю у меня в ASCII. Надо как-то сделать его тоже в UTF-8

Ночной танец с бубном вокруг `mb_convert_variables` и `iconv` для элементов массива $vars не дал результатов, прошу помощи. Нужна либо новая идея либо правильное техническое решение текущей идеи.

---

Говорят, ничего не понятно... Упрощу. Есть массив, ключи которого указаны украинскими буквами. Если я пишу просто `print_r($item['Цiна'])` - просто обращаюсь к массиву, чтоб в качестве эксперимента получить значение элемента, то всё работает, я получаю значение, но если я делаю это в цикле

```
$item = [
            [....] => ....
            [TGroup] => 23
            [Кількість у залишку] => 1
            [Ціна] => 84.30
];
foreach ($item as $k => $val){
   print_r($item[$k])
}
```

то распечатываются не все элементы массива. Также через array_key_exist не находит некоторые ключи

Comment: Много букв и ничего не понятно ...

Comment: когда дампишь код, то получаешь вот такие вещи в разных массивах: string(10) "Ціна" и string(11) "Ціна". Т.е. на каком-то "внутреннем уровне" ключ в одном массиве у меня string(11), а в другом такой же с виду ключ  string(10) . Поэтому я и не могу найти один ключ одного массива в другом массиве. Вопрос: как преобразовать украинские переменные в единый формат?

Comment: Хмм, ви використовуєте якусь бібліотеку яка вертає вам масив з csv як ключ => значення?

Comment: @Oughtem, киньте два таких одинаковых слова, но в разной кодировке. P. S. Вот так понятней намного)